# Android spinner using array adapter not showing all data

Tags: android, android-spinner

i'm trying to build an app using google maps v2. my objective is try to get user current location and then show them nearby places via spinner1. if user choose e.g Hospital, then on the map it will show markers to hospital. Below is the result in logcat .

[image: Logcat]

So, i add another spinner (spinner2) to right of spinner1 to store all of those Hospital name. as you can see, on the logcat there's 20 hospitals, but my problem is on the spinner2, it only showing 1 hospital.

[image: result]

How can i add those 20 data to spinner2?? here's my code :

```
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list){

        gmapv2.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
            MarkerOptions m_opt = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> hash_tempat = list.get(i);
            double llat = Double.parseDouble(hash_tempat.get("lat"));
            double llong = Double.parseDouble(hash_tempat.get("lng"));
            String nama = hash_tempat.get("place_name");
            //Log.d("dari gg ke hendy", nama);
            String vici = hash_tempat.get("vicinity");
            Log.d("dari gg ke hendy", nama + " " + vici);
            LatLng ab_latLng = new LatLng(llat, llong);
            m_opt.position(ab_latLng);
            m_opt.title(nama + " : " + vici);
            m_opt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
            Marker e = gmapv2.addMarker(m_opt);
            detailTempat.put(e.getId(), hash_tempat.get("reference"));

            adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Places_On_Resta_Map.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<String>());
            adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerDetail.setAdapter(adapt);
            adapt.add(nama);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.
Environment : Windows 7, Eclipse, Genymotion.

Comment: Its because you have added `new ArrayList<String>()` so it will each and every time create new arraylist.

Comment: @GrlsHu can you please help me at this post?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581256/how-to-animate-google-map-v2-marker-on-the-polyline-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
   ArrayList<String> myArray;
 for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
        MarkerOptions m_opt = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> hash_tempat = list.get(i);
        double llat = Double.parseDouble(hash_tempat.get("lat"));
        double llong = Double.parseDouble(hash_tempat.get("lng"));
        String nama = hash_tempat.get("place_name");
        myArray.add(nama);

        String vici = hash_tempat.get("vicinity");
        Log.d("dari gg ke hendy", nama + " " + vici);
        LatLng ab_latLng = new LatLng(llat, llong);
        m_opt.position(ab_latLng);
        m_opt.title(nama + " : " + vici);
        m_opt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
        Marker e = gmapv2.addMarker(m_opt);
        detailTempat.put(e.getId(), hash_tempat.get("reference"));
    }

      adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Places_On_Resta_Map.this, 
       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArray); //Change your array here
        adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerDetail.setAdapter(adapt);
      pDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: @GrlsHu sorry if you don't mind, i read on your post about animating marker on google map v2, can you help me on this post --> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581256/how-to-animate-google-map-v2-marker-on-the-polyline-path` thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list){

    gmapv2.clear();
    adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Places_On_Resta_Map.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<String>());
    adapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
        MarkerOptions m_opt = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> hash_tempat = list.get(i);
        double llat = Double.parseDouble(hash_tempat.get("lat"));
        double llong = Double.parseDouble(hash_tempat.get("lng"));
        String nama = hash_tempat.get("place_name");
        //Log.d("dari gg ke hendy", nama);
        String vici = hash_tempat.get("vicinity");
        Log.d("dari gg ke hendy", nama + " " + vici);
        LatLng ab_latLng = new LatLng(llat, llong);
        m_opt.position(ab_latLng);
        m_opt.title(nama + " : " + vici);
        m_opt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
        Marker e = gmapv2.addMarker(m_opt);
        detailTempat.put(e.getId(), hash_tempat.get("reference"));

        adapt.add(nama);//<---------
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
   spinnerDetail.setAdapter(adapt);//<---------
}
```