# how can i animate this marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

can anyone help me please? I want to animate the "bus" marker I've seen a lot of videos and tutorials but I can't make it work I'm newbie to android, this is the only thing i'm missing for the completion of my app,i want the marker to move through the polyline thank you very much for your help!

This is the code:

```
package com.example.alejandro.integradora2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class RutaUtd extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    TextView info;

    LatLng latLng;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocation, bus,finr;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }



    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng inicio = new LatLng(23.989444, -104.617897);
        LatLng fin = new LatLng(24.032782, -104.639596);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(inicio).title("Inicio Ruta").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fin).title("Fin Ruta"));
        bus= mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.996506, -104.638496)).title("Ubicacion del Bus").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus)));
        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(24.005651, -104.600266), 12));

        PolylineOptions RutaIda = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(23.989444, -104.617897),new LatLng(23.996506, -104.638496),new LatLng(23.996741, -104.638694),new LatLng(23.998000, -104.638673),new LatLng(23.998720, -104.639027),
                        new LatLng(24.000460, -104.640336),new LatLng(24.001126, -104.641189),new LatLng(24.001479, -104.642369),new LatLng(24.002038, -104.643131),new LatLng(24.004086, -104.644274),
                        new LatLng(24.005674, -104.644124),new LatLng(24.006680, -104.644261),new LatLng(24.021361, -104.645530),new LatLng(24.026858, -104.645884),new LatLng(24.032508, -104.639628),
                        new LatLng(24.032831, -104.638727),new LatLng(24.032851, -104.636989),new LatLng(24.033086, -104.636957),new LatLng(24.033194, -104.639135),new LatLng(24.032782, -104.639596))
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.RED);
        Polyline polyline = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(RutaIda);

        PolylineOptions RutaVuelta = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(24.032782, -104.639596),new LatLng(24.027185, -104.645781),new LatLng(24.025901, -104.645888),new LatLng(24.006594, -104.644299),new LatLng(24.004761, -104.644396),
                        new LatLng(24.003761, -104.644267),new LatLng(24.002016, -104.643237),new LatLng(24.001085, -104.641488),new LatLng(24.000634, -104.640619),new LatLng(23.998919, -104.639366),
                        new LatLng(23.998203, -104.638894),new LatLng(23.997017, -104.638862),new LatLng(23.996596, -104.639184),new LatLng(23.989328, -104.618017)

                )
                .width(8)
                .color(Color.parseColor("#802E2EFE"));
        //.color(Color.BLUE);

        Polyline ruta = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(RutaVuelta);

    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Unregister for location callbacks:
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            //place marker at current position

            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Posicion Actual");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocation = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //remove previous current location marker and add new one at current position
        if (mCurrLocation != null) {
            mCurrLocation.remove();
        }
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocation = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //Toast.makeText(this,"Location Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //If you only need one location, unregister the listener
        //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        info= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distancia);

        LatLng autobus=bus.getPosition();
        // LatLng markerLatLng = marker.getPosition();
        Location bus = new Location("");
        bus.setLatitude(autobus.latitude);
        bus.setLongitude(autobus.longitude);
        float distancia=mLastLocation.distanceTo(bus)/1000;

        info.setText("El camion se encuentra a "+distancia+" km aproximadamente de tu ubicacion");






    }




}
```

Comment: Which type of animation you want? I have code for bounce animation.. Do you want that?

Comment: oh  i'm sorry i forgot that, i want the marker to move through the polyline

Comment: but this is for javascript, im working with android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581256/how-to-animate-google-map-v2-marker-on-the-polyline-path